# can anyone explain the mechanics behind this weird behavior of braces ( ) and curly braces { } in the following code in c++?

Tags: c++, constructor

The detail is a little bit long to formulate, and I have broken down the problem I'm facing into 3 "rounds", so bear with me...

For the first round, consider the following C++ code, which is error-free and one that behaves as expected:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

class rect{
    float width;
    float length;
    
public:
    rect( float w = 5, float l=8 ) : width(w), length(l) {}
    float area(){return width * length;}
};
    
class box{
    rect base;
    float height;
public:
    box(rect a={2,7}, float c=9) : base(a), height(c){ }  //round 1
    //box(rect a={2}, float c=9) : base(a), height(c){ }  //round  2 option 1
    //box(rect a=(2), float c=9) : base(a), height(c){ }  //round 2 option 2
    //box(rect a=(2,7), float c=9) : base(a), height(c){ }  //round 3
        
    float volume(){return base.area() * height;}
};
    
int main(){
    rect a;
    cout<<"Area a= "<<a.area()<<endl; 
    
    rect b(3,4);
    cout<<"Area b= "<<b.area()<<endl; 
    
    rect c(3);
    cout<<"Area c= "<<c.area()<<endl; 
    
    box d(a,6);
    cout<<"Volume d= "<<d.volume()<<endl;
    
    box e(a);
    cout<<"Volume e= "<<e.volume()<<endl;
    
    box f;
    cout<<"Volume f= "<<f.volume()<<endl;

    return 0;
}
```

When I run the code, it outputs:

```
Area a= 40
Area b= 12
Area c= 24
Volume d= 240
Volume e= 360
Volume f= 126
```

Analyzing the result:

- `Area a= 40` since width of `a` is set to 5 and length of `a` is set to 8 by the default constructor
- `Area b= 12` since width of `b` is set to 3 and length of `b` is set to 4 from the arguments
- `Area c= 24` since width of `c` is set to `3` from the argument, and since argument for length of `c` is missing, it is set to `8` from the default constructor value for length in class `rect`
- `Volume d= 240` since rect `a` is `5 x 6` from default constructor in class `rect`, and height of box `d` is 6 from argument
- `Volume e= 360` since rect `a` is `5 x 6` from default constructor in class `rect`, and height of box `e` is 9 from default constructor in class `box`
- `Volume f= 126` outputs 126 since rect of `f` is `2 x 7` from default constructor in class `box`, and height of box `e` is 9 from default constructor in class `box`

Next, for round 2, replace the `box` class constructor line by round 2 option 1:

`box(rect a={2}, float c=9) : base(a), height(c){ }`

Or by option 2:

`box(rect a=(2), float c=9) : base(a), height(c){ }`

Note the change from curly brace in `rect a={2}` to normal braces `rect a=(2)`

Now, running the above code, both constructor declarations (`rect a={2}` and `rect a=(2)`) will give the following output:

```
Area a= 40 //same logic as in round 1
Area b= 12 //same logic as in round 1
Area c= 24 //same logic as in round 1
Volume d= 240 //same logic as in round 1
Volume e= 360 //same logic as in round 1
Volume f= 126 //output changed because width for rect of f is 2 from default constructor in class box
// since length default value in class a is missing, length for rect of f is set to 8 from default constructor in class rect
// height of box e is 9 from default constructor in class box
```

Note for round 2, the code gives the same output in both constructor declarations options 1 and 2 (`rect a={2}` & `rect a=(2)`).

So far, everything is working as it should.

Next, for the final and mayhem round, replace the `box` class constructor by option 3:

`box(rect a=(2,7), float c=9) : base(a), height(c){ }`

Note the normal braces in `rect a=(2,7)`.

Every other result stays the same (because they are not affected by the change) except for `Volume f`, which is a whopping `504`. By my observation, the compiler has chosen:

- width 7, from `rect a=(2,7)`
- length 8 from default width in `rect` class
- height 9 from default height from `box` class itself

The choice for height is logical, but the choice for width and length is confusing.

Can anybody explain the mechanics behind this?

My expectation was, round 3 should behave exactly as round 1, since round 2 option 1 & round 2 option 2 are behaving the same.

My question in summary is, what brought about the difference declaring a constructor for a class containing another class member as round 1 curly braces and as round 3 normal braces?

Comment: Are you aware that in C++, `(2,7)` is simply `7`, due to the built-in [comma operator](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_other#Built-in_comma_operator)?

Comment: For option 3 to work as you expected you should write `rect a=rect(2,7)` instead of `rect a=(2,7)`. List initialization is working only with `{}`. See here: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/list_initialization

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`rect a={2,7}` will invoke the `rect` constructor with two input values, `w=2` and `l=7`.

`rect a=(2,7)` will first invoke the [comma operator](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_other#Built-in_comma_operator) (which in this case will return `7`), and then will invoke the `rect` constructor with one input value, `w=7`, leaving the `l` parameter to use its default value.